# Drawing on surface in edit mode and saving as texture

Tags: uv, texture-baking, annotation, seams

I create a lot of foam patterns, and I do this by UV unwrapping 3D models, then exporting them as a .svg to Inkscape to edit. However I lose a lot of time going back and forth trying to figure out where to add edge ID's and registration marks (to judge where to align the foam).

What would really speed up the process would be to draw the edge ID's and registration marks on the model itself in Blender, then export the texture, so that I then have an image texture to import with my UV outlines and have all the information immediately present in Inkscape.

[image: Example with edge ID's drawn with annotations]
Example with edge ID's drawn with annotations

But I'm struggling to find a way to do this. Adding annotations in edit mode is easy enough, but there doesn't seem to be a way to export annotations as a texture. And it doesn't seem that texture paint will work either, because I need to be able to see the marked seams on the model.

Is there a way, with or without addons, that I could easily draw on a model (while being able to see seams) and then export the drawing to an image texture?

Comment: [Texture Painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/index.html) seems an obvious route, here, either for the annotations, or the foam itself.. in the latter case, you'd just paint straight over the seams and the registration would be handled for you..

Comment: The problem with texture painting is that I can't see the seams whilst in that mode - however, I did find a work around for that, which I will write up in an answer soon. It's basically just duplicating the seam edges into a different object, so I can select them and have them highlighted when texture painting.